# How to adjust the size of a CDockablePane?

Tags: c++, mfc

I am writing a SDI application on Visual Studio 2012. The MFC Wizard generated two `CDockablePane`-derived objects. The right-side `CPropertiesWnd` (`CDockablePane`-derived) object is named `m_wndProperties`. I embed in `m_wndProperties` a `CPropertySheet` object with a `CPageNone` (`CPropertyPage`-derived) object captioned "HELP" [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVp1U.jpg) (I use the `CPropertySheet` class directly). However, the real size of the `CPropertySheet` object is [bigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPYmv.jpg).

I have tried to adjust the size of the dialog related to the `CPageNone` object (named `m_pageNone`) in the Dialog Editor. This has no effect. In the `MainFrm.cpp`, the only lines relating to `m_wndProperties` I can find are:

```
int CMainFrame::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
{
    .....
    m_wndProperties.EnableDocking(CBRS_ALIGN_RIGHT);
    DockPane(&m_wndProperties);
    .....
}

.....

BOOL CMainFrame::CreateDockingWindows()
{
    .....
    CString strPropertiesWnd;
    bNameValid = strPropertiesWnd.LoadString(IDS_PROPERTIES_WND);
    ASSERT(bNameValid);
    if (!m_wndProperties.Create(strPropertiesWnd, this, CRect(0, 0, 200, 200), TRUE, ID_VIEW_PROPERTIESWND, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_CLIPCHILDREN | CBRS_RIGHT | CBRS_FLOAT_MULTI))
    {
        TRACE0("無法建立 [屬性] 視窗\n");
        return FALSE; // 無法建立
    }
    .....
}

.....

void CMainFrame::SetDockingWindowIcons(BOOL bHiColorIcons)
{
    .....
    HICON hPropertiesBarIcon = (HICON) ::LoadImage(::AfxGetResourceHandle(), MAKEINTRESOURCE(bHiColorIcons ? IDI_PROPERTIES_WND_HC : IDI_PROPERTIES_WND), IMAGE_ICON, ::GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSMICON), ::GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSMICON), 0);
    m_wndProperties.SetIcon(hPropertiesBarIcon, FALSE);

}
```

And here is the `AdjustLayout()` in my `PropertiesWnd.cpp`:

```
void CPropertiesWnd::AdjustLayout()
{
    if (GetSafeHwnd () == NULL || (AfxGetMainWnd() != NULL && AfxGetMainWnd()->IsIconic()))
    {
        return;
    }

    CRect rectClient;
    GetClientRect(rectClient);

    m_PropertySheet.SetWindowPos (NULL, rectClient.left, rectClient.top, rectClient.Width (), rectClient.Height (), SWP_NOACTIVATE | SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOSIZE);
}
```

And in my `PageNone.cpp`, I only have three functions: the default constructor, the default destructor and `DoDataExchange`.

My question is how can I adjust the size of `m_wndProperties` or `m_pageNone` to fit each other? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I have got this working in a different way (the code is too large to give in this answer, but the main points are:

a) don't do anything in `CMainFrame::OnCreate()`

b) in `CMainFrame::CreateDockingWindows()`, after `m_wndProperties.Create()`, add the following code

```
m_PropertySheet.Create(...);
CRect rc;
m_PropertySheet.GetRect(&rc);
m_wndProperties.SetMinSize(rc.Width(), rc,Height());
m_wndProperties.EnableDocking(CBRS_ALIGN_RIGHT);
DockPane(&m_wndProperties);
ShowPane(&m_wndProperties, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code in `AdjustLayout()` is plausible right, but I think during startup it will be called too early. Because the default size will be read from `CWinAppEx::LoadState()`, which always read the previous size from the Registry. It can probably disabled with `CWinAppEx::EnableLoadWindowPlacement(FALSE)`. not tested.

Post a User-Defined Message at the end of `InitInstance()`. Or just try with a timer in `CMainFrame::Create() .. SetTimer(123,2000,NULL);`

```
void CMainFrame::OnTimer(UINT_PTR nIDEvent)
{
    if (nIDEvent == 123)
    {
        m_wndProperties.SetWindowPos(this, 0, 0, 400, 200, SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_FRAMECHANGED);
        RecalcLayout();
        KillTimer(123);
    }

    CFrameWndEx::OnTimer(nIDEvent);
}
```